# the dl4j web ui wont update or do anything it just says loading in every category

Tags: java, user-interface, dl4j

i have started to try to use deeplearning4j just to mess around with it and im doing alright so far i fixed the gendertester but id like to ask how to get the ui to make graphs and update all i can get is text and everything says "loading" the whole time.

this is the part of the code that i thought would make it work from the examples

```
 MultiLayerNetwork model = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
            model.init();
            UIServer uiServer = UIServer.getInstance();

            StatsStorage statsStorage = new InMemoryStatsStorage();
            uiServer.attach(statsStorage);
            uiServer.enableRemoteListener();

            model.setListeners(new StatsListener(statsStorage,1),new ScoreIterationListener(50));
```

any tips or advice would be great id really like to pick this up as a hobby, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileNotFoundException

Windows 10 user folder name had spaces in it and the spaces were recognized as %20. I made a new user with no spaces and it ran perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try adapting our UI example, this shows example usage:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/userInterface/UIExample.java

Comment: i already ran that from the examples and it shows in the web page but everything just says "loading"

Comment: That should be working out of the box - if you want live help come to our gitter: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j